# Control-M on-do condition when Job ended

Tags: control-m

I want to add a step (On-Do) to delete a condition in Control-M V7 when a job ends (no matter which result: either OK, NOTOK, exception from OS, etc.). I've accomplished the same in Control-M V9 with the next syntax:

[image]

```
 <ON STMT="*" CODE="COMPSTAT EQ ANY">
       <DOCOND NAME="MY_CONDITION" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="DEL" />
 </ON>
```

However, if I implement it in Ctrl-M V7, the code `COMPSTAT EQ ANY` is not recognized throwing the next validation error:

[image: Control-M V7]

> The On/Statement value 'COMPSTAT EQ ANY' is not valid. Please correct
> the definitions to COMPSTAT  <completion_code>.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "ANY". The best way is to cover all options with 2 ons -

```
On Statement   Stmt=*   Code=COMPSTAT=0
Do OK

On Statement   Stmt=*   Code=COMPSTAT!0
Do OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want changing the filter (write * on code):

[image: Control-M 7 Filter]

In only one line